# Reply to the same thread in mattermost with webhook

Tags: json, webhooks, mattermost

I am using a webhook to post the message to mattermost everytime a post is created in an ITSM. I want to post the message as a thread everytime somebody does some activity on the same post.

````
{"text": " | Incident Update |  |\n| --- | --- |\n| Incident |  {#subject#} |\n| Downtime | {#createdTime#} |\n| Uptime | {#request.lastClosedTime#}  |\n| Root Cause |  {#Problem Domain#}  |\n| Duration |  |\n| Escalation Level | 1 |\n| Escalation To | Network Operations |\n| Area |  {#Area#}  |\n| Priority |  {#priority#}  |\n| Impact |  {#impact#}  |\n| Category |  {#category#}  |\n| Affected Area |  |\n| Remarks | {#comment#}  {#Solution#}  |\n" }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, as you can see in the following link: https://mattermost.uservoice.com/forums/306457-general/suggestions/37237117-allow-webhooks-to-post-to-reply-threads, this characteristic is not yet supported by mattermost and is still in the "proposal" stage with no implementation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).